# How can I get a list of all keys of dicts inside a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have a list of dicts that looks like this:

```
[{1: "a"}, {2: "b"}]
```

How can I get a list of all keys of the listed dicts (meaning [1, 2])?

Comment: Does each dictionary have only one entry? If so, you'd do better to store your data as `{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}` or `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = [{1: "a"}, {2: "b"}]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(l))
[1, 2]
```

Or, if you use a list comprehension, you can skip the `.keys()`. In python 2.x you also avoid building an unnecessary list that way:

```
>>> [k for d in l for k in d]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid an extra import, you can of use a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [{1: 'a'}, {2: 'b'}]
>>> [k for d in l for k in d.keys()]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following code, you don't need to import something.

```
>>> map(lambda x: x.keys()[0], [{1: "a"}, {2: "b"}])
[1, 2]
```

though it's not clean...

Answer (score 1):

Very simple method (without importing anything):

```
d = [{1: "a"}, {2: "b"}]
keys = [l.keys() for l in d]
```

However, this returns `[[1], [2]]`.

To avoid that, you can change this to:

```
d = [{1: "a"}, {2: "b"}]
keys = []
for l in d:
    for key in l: # iterating through a dictionary always gives the key
        keys.append(key)
```

The [list-comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions) equivalent of the above is:

```
d = [{1: "a"}, {2: "b"}]
keys = [key for l in d for key in l.keys()]
```

You can also use the [built-in `d.update(d2)` feature](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update), which combines dictionaries:

```
d = [{1: "a"}, {2: "b"}]
new_dict = {}
for l in d: new_dict.update(l)
new_dict.keys()
```

This would overwrite one of the key-value pairs if the two dictionaries had two of the same key (like `[{1: 'a'}, {1: 'b'}]`).

Answer (score 0):

`sum((m.keys() for m in l), [])` if you want a list,

`set(sum((m.keys() for m in l), []))` if you want a set.

Comment: While that'll work, it'll show quadratic behaviour (if the list is ten times longer, it'll take 100 times longer to do the sum).